# how Add new kernel to jupyter notebook from virtualenv

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

how Add new kernel to jupyter notebook from virtualenv ,

I have a python here :

```
/home/p002710/venv/bin/python3.6 ->  /data/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.1.0/bin/python3.6 (Symbolic Link )
```

I want add this python as a new kernel to my jupyter notebook.

here is what I tried :

1 - `ipython kernel install --name "local-venv" --user`

2 - `cd ~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/local-venv/`

3 - `vim kernel.json`

4 - replace

```
"argv": [
  "/data/Anaconda/Anaconda3-5.1.0/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "local-venv",
 "language": "python"
}
```

with

```
  {
 "argv": [
  "/home/p002710/venv/bin/python3.6",       
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "local-venv",
 "language": "python3.6"
}
```